# How to configure second instance of drupal to run from subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have drupal installed in the root folder of the webserver. There is also a custom drupal app that is now running from root/subfolder. I have configured settings.php to recognize $base_url and changed .htaccess to rewrite base to /subfolder.

At the moment, it works great in terms of logging in and making content changes. However, trying to upload files returns an ajax error, if I try to save directly by pressing save, it doesn't return an error on the subfolder site, rather it throws back a 404 on the root site.

What gives? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that is thrown? whats the permission on /default/files directory?

Comment: The permission on default/files directory is 777, I changed it to that to make sure it's writable by everyone. However on the default folder, I changed permissions to 555 **error being thrown** _An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /rfp/?q=file/ajax/field_files/und/form-iAGpjAtrg5l7mQdDjHQ57CqHH_48XVS2E6CM-uj1xho
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: 
Jump to Navigation
var_ The "rfp" text there is the name of the subfolder site.